# Como incrementar un campo con varios registros relacionados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día comunidad, tengo una tabla donde un usuario tiene varios registros como se ve en el ejemplo de abajo y quiero insertar esos datos en otra tabla ¿como puedo hacer para incrementar IdMovimiento de forma que salga 13,14,15...etc? Intenté haciendo un SELECT MAX(IdMovimiento) + 1 pero al hacer eso me coloca en todos 14 y no consecutivamente como lo necesito. Espero haberme dado a entender

Gracias de antemano.

| IdMovimiento | NoMovimiento |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 10091 |
| 13 | 10092 |
| 13 | 10092 |

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo que has intentado